# Should a class with only static methods be abstract?

Tags: java

I have a class that offers a collection of static utility-type methods.

On the one hand, I don't want the class to be able to be instantiated. On the other hand, I don't want to send the signal that the class should be inherited from (not that I think that it's likely).

Should this class be abstract or not?

Answer (score 15):

Make the class `final` and make the default constructor `private` and do not provide any `public` constructors. That way no one can subclass it or create an instance of it.

Comment: And to prevent instantiate it with reflection throw RuntimeException inside constructor :D

Comment: Of course, if someone on the project is trying to instantiate such a class, then the project is probably screwed anyway, so really it's a waste of time to even worry about this stuff.

Comment: @mre My comment was slightly tongue-in-cheek, but not particularly cryptic.  Obviously, your world is completely black and white.

Answer (score 8):

Don't declare it `abstract`; declare a `private` constructor, so no one, not even a subclass, can instantiate an instance of your utility class.

You can declare your class `final`, although if all constructors are `private`, then no one will be able to subclass it anyway.

To borrow the idea from Pshemo's comment in another answer, throw a RuntimeException in the constructor to prevent reflection's `setAccessible` method in [AccessibleObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html) from allowing instantiation:

```
public class MyUtility
{
   private MyUtility()
   {
      throw new RuntimeException("Instantiation of MyUtility is not allowed!");
   }

   public static void utilityMethod()
   {
      // Your utility method here.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although a top-level class can't be declared `static`, you can make the class non-instantiable (and practically 'static') to other classes by declaring the default constructor `private`, which forbids instantiation because no constructor is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, you don't have to do *anything*. Nothing bad will happen, nobody is going to instantiate/subclass your class.

Comment: +1  Agreed.  This is an accident that never happens.  It's like putting up guardrails on a road in the desert that no one ever drives along anyway.

Comment: ... in a totally flat desert, where nothing bad would happen if the car left the road. At worst, needlessly creating an instance will cause a (in the vast majority of cases, totally negligible) reduction in performance. Surely we have more important things to care about?

Answer (score 2):

Another version of [@mre's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584862/mre) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14886603/1393766)

```
enum MyClass{
    ;//this semicolon indicates that this enum will have no instances

    //now you can put your methods
    public static void myMethod(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Enum by default is final and its constructor is private. Also you cant create its instance with reflection because it checks in [Constructor#newInstance](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java?av=f#519) if you are trying to instantiate Enum object.

Comment: +1, out-of-the-box.  But it does suffer from using the enum type in an unintended way that belies the meaning of "enum".

Answer (score 1):

What is contained in a class has no bearing on whether it should be abstract. The key take away: an abstract class *must* have another class extending it (a 'concrete' class); only that concrete class can be instantiated.

To prevent it from being extended, use `final`.

To prevent it from being instantiated, make the constructor `private`.

Observe that in Java these are discrete concepts.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is a utility class.
It should be `final` with a `private` default constuctor, to avoid instantiation.
If you have checkstyle enabled you would get a warning if you dont do it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other calls to give the class a private constructor, you should also make it final so that it is clear nothing can subclass it.

```
public final class Utils
{
    // prevent accidental construction.
    private Utils() 
    {  
    } 

    public static void foo()
    { 
        //util code here
    }
}
```